# injector.getInstance of a generic type in Guice without interface

Tags: java, generics, guice, inject

I would like to be able to get Objects based on Generic type using Guice.

```
Class Sample<T>{
 private T value;
}

Class Type1 {
}

Class Type2 {
}

 Simple<Type1> simpleValue1 = injector.getInstance(?);
 Simple<Type2> simpleValue2 = injector.getInstance(?);
```

Could you please suggest me what should I pass in 'getInstance'?

Note: Class Type1 and Class Type2 are importing from other jars so not possible to write common interface.

Comment: Try `Key.get(new TypeLiteral<Sample<Type1>>() {})`.

Answer (score 0):

```
As @Louis Wasserman mentioned Below code working for me.Thanks @Louis Wasserman.

Sample<Type1> repo1 = injector.getInstance(new Key<Sample<Type1>>() {});
Sample<Type2> repo2 = injector.getInstance(new Key<Sample<Type2>>() {});
```